# Show selection of TEdit that does not have focus

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, c++builder, delphi-10.2-tokyo, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I have a FireMonkey application and I need to change what is selected in `Edit1` while the user is typing in `Edit2`. To be exact, `Edit1` has some sample text and `Edit2` has a regular expression that the user is editing. I want the user to be able to see if the regular expression is valid and what the matched text would be for the given sample text.

I'm using the `OnChangeTracking` event of `Edit2` to set the `SelStart` and `SelLength` of `Edit1`.

The problem is, unlike VCL's `TEdit`, FireMonkey's `TEdit` does not have a `HideSelection` property, and always hides the selected text if the control does not have the input focus.

Is there a way to change this behavior and force the selection highlight to show no matter which control has input focus?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. This is hard-coded behavior, `TEdit` checks its `IsFocused` property before painting a selection. So, you will have to re-think how your UI shows the result of applying the regular expression to the sample text.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks. I replaced the sample `TEdit` with a `TMemo` which does have a `HideSelectionOnExit` property and that took care of the problem.